# Block multiple keypress events that has same timestamp

Tags: fedora, xorg, keyboard, keyboard-event

I have a faulty keyboard that will fire additional keys when i press a single key.
for example,
when i click letter "D" on keyboard it will send  "D5"

```
$xev -event keyboard

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x929, subw 0x0, time 7185644, (351,334), root:(2087,693),
    state 0x10, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x929, subw 0x0, time 7185644, (351,334), root:(2087,693),
    state 0x10, keycode 84 (keysym 0xffb5, KP_5), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (35) "5"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (35) "5"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x929, subw 0x0, time 7185716, (351,334), root:(2087,693),
    state 0x10, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    root 0x929, subw 0x0, time 7185716, (351,334), root:(2087,693),
    state 0x10, keycode 84 (keysym 0xffb5, KP_5), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (35) "5"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

notice that both keypress events have the same timestamp.
my question is,
is there a way to block the second keyPress event if it has the same timestamp as the previous keyPress  event?

or is there any other way to block this second input?

Answer (score 1):

A solution that requires some Python coding should be possible using the [evdev](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to read events from the keyboard, filter them to suppress the second event with the same timestamp, and then inject them into a new uinput keyboard device.

Examples of parts of the code that will be needed are in the Python evdev tutorial, such as [create uninput device with capabilities of another device](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#create-uinput-device-with-capabilities-of-another-device), and on the same page,
*Listing accessible event devices*,
*Listing device capabilities* to find the keyboard,
*Reading events* with the timestamp, and
*Injecting input*.

See also the [grab](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apidoc.html?highlight=grab#evdev.device.InputDevice.grab) function, to stop the original keyboard events going on to the X11 server.

---

Alternatively, there is a highly configurable utility [evsieve](https://github.com/KarsMulder/evsieve) that can do many sorts of filtering between an input keyboard and a created uinput output keyboard device. I am not familiar with the program, which is written in Rust, but you will probably have to add some code in that language to recognise and suppress events with the same timestamp.

Comment: evsieve looks really intresting. i'll give it a try.